# Free data source for options IV and volatility data (US, UK, EUR Equities preferable)?

Tags: market-data, data, historical-data

Where can I get free options implied volatility and realized volatility data?

I used to use Quandl, but they were acquired by NASDAQ and now offer this data under a premium paywall.

For reference, I am using this for individual purposes only.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi @DimitriVulis, thanks a lot for sharing- that's the link I consulted before posting.

Unfortunately, all of the above listed data vendors are premium. I'm looking for one that's preferably free.

Comment: I understand that you looked there and didn’t find what you needed. I still closed this question since the linked question should be the place where online data sources are listed, not in individual questions.